# Nested for loop for accumulating numbers and printing the names

Tags: python

I have 2 lists as follows

```
names=['jon','adam','jessica','aaron']
nums=[1,5,7,9]
```

i am writing a nested for loop for getting the output like below

```
jon starts from 5 to 6
adam starts from 6 to 11
jessica starts from 11 to 18
aaron starts from 18 to 27
```

I need to accumulate the numbers in nums list and add them to a starting number i give and then use the corresponding names in the names list, the ending number of the previous name should be the starting number for the next name, i have written code as follows

```
names=['jon','adam','jessica','aaron']
nums=[1,5,7,9]
from itertools import accumulate
a= accumulate(nums)

for j in names:
    start = 5
    for i in a:
        starts=start+i
        print(j,"starts from",start, "to",starts)
        start=starts
```

this gives me the following output

```
jon starts from 5 to 6
jon starts from 6 to 12
jon starts from 12 to 25
jon starts from 25 to 47
```

Here the names are not appearing as expected as well the numbers are not accumulated correctly as well, what should be done to fix this

Comment: What's the logic for your _starts from ... to ..._ display? You want to sum the numbers in the `nums` list with the number `5`?

Comment: Yes i want to sum the numbers with number 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using a nested for loop, which will print out everyone's name next to each number... but it didn't.  The reason why it didn't is because `accumulate` is an iterator that reaches the end after the first loop.  So, I decided to `zip` the two together.  I also used a format string (Python 3.6, if you can't use format strings, then use `.format`).  I also renamed most of the variables.  Additionally, I don't think you really to use `accumulate` at all that seems to be where all the confusion is coming from.

```
names = ['jon','adam','jessica','aaron']
ages = [1,5,7,9]

start = 5
for name, age in zip(names, ages):
    end = start + age
    print(f"{name} starts from {start} to {end}")
    start = end
```

Output:

```
jon starts from 5 to 6
adam starts from 6 to 11
jessica starts from 11 to 18
aaron starts from 18 to 27
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `enumerate` in order to solve your question.
Here is an example:

```
def accumulate(names, nums):
    start = 5
    for k, v in enumerate(names):
        s = start + nums[k]
        print(v, 'starts from ', start, 'to', s)
        start = s

names=['jon','adam','jessica','aaron']
nums=[1,5,7,9]

accumulate(names, nums)
```

Output:

```
jon starts from  5 to 6
adam starts from  6 to 11
jessica starts from  11 to 18
aaron starts from  18 to 27
```

PS: the length of `nums` must be inferior or equal to the length of `names` otherwise there will be an exception.